# I have employee table and User table for user account creation in my db and need to get employees without user account and getting an error

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Employee Entity

```
@Entity //applied as an entity class
@Table(name="employee") // map to given table
@Data //generate getter setter
@NoArgsConstructor //generate default constructor
@AllArgsConstructor //generate all argument constructor
public class Employee {


    @Id //primary key
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)//AI
    @Column(name="id" ,unique = true)//for map with column
    private Integer id ;

    @Column(name="empnumber" , unique = true)
    @NotNull
    @Length(max = 10)
    private String empnumber ;

    @Column(name="fullname")
    @NotNull
    private String fullname ;

    @Column(name="callingname")
    @NotNull
    private String callingname ;

    @Column(name="nic",unique = true)
    @NotNull
    @Length(max = 12,min = 10)
    private String nic ;

    @Column(name="email",unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String email  ;

    @Column(name="mobile")
    @NotNull
    @Length(max = 10)
    private String mobile ;

    @Column(name="landno")
    @Length(max = 10)
    private String landno  ;


    @Column(name="address")
    @NotNull
    private String  address;

    @Column(name="note")
    private String  note ;

    @Column(name="civilstatus")
    @NotNull
    private String civilstatus ;

    @Column(name="gender")
    @NotNull
    private String gender;

    @Column(name="dateofbirth")
    @NotNull
    private LocalDate dateofbirth;


    @Column(name="addeddatetime")
    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime addeddatetime;


    @Column(name="lastmodifydatetime")
    private LocalDateTime lastmodifydatetime;

    @Column(name="deletedatetime")
    private LocalDateTime deletedatetime;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employeestatus_id", referencedColumnName = "id")//join column condition
    private EmployeeStatus employeestatus_id ;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "designation_id", referencedColumnName  = "id")
    private Designation designation_id ;
}
```

Employee Contoller

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDao dao;

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeStatusDao statusDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee")
    public ModelAndView empUi() {
        ModelAndView viewEp = new ModelAndView();
        viewEp.setViewName("employee.html");

        return viewEp;
    }

   ** //    get employees who don't have a  user account
    @GetMapping(value ="/employee/empwithoutuseraccount" ,produces = "application/json")
    public List<Employee> getEmployeeListWithoutUserAccount(){
       return dao.getEmployeeListWithoutUserAccount();
    }
**
    @GetMapping(value = "/employee/findall", produces = "application/json")
    public List<Employee> findall() {
        return dao.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id"));
    }

    //post mapping to add employee record to database
    @PostMapping(value = "/employee")
    public String save(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
//        authentication and authorization need to come

        try {
            //            check nic exists in Database
            Employee extNic = dao.getEmployeeByNic(employee.getNic());

            if (extNic != null) {
                return "save not successful nic exists ";
            }
            Employee extEmail = dao.getEmployeeByEmail(employee.getEmail());

            if (extEmail != null) {
                return "save not successful email exists ";
            }
            employee.setAddeddatetime(LocalDateTime.now());

            String nextEmpno = dao.getNextEmpno();

            if (nextEmpno.equals("") || nextEmpno.equals(null)) {
                employee.setEmpnumber("00000001");
            } else {
                employee.setEmpnumber(nextEmpno);     // emp no auto generated
            }
            dao.save(employee);
            return "OK";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Save not successfull" + e.getMessage();
        }


    }

    








}
```

Employee dao

```
import com.suwasethaclinic.entity.Employee;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import java.util.List;

public interface EmployeeDao extends JpaRepository<Employee,Integer> {


   **@Query(value = "SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.id not in (SELECT  u.employee_id FROM User u)")
   public List<Employee> getEmployeeListWithoutUserAccount();**
}
```

user entity

```
@Entity //applied as an entity class
@Table(name="user") // map to given table
@Data //generate getter setter
@NoArgsConstructor //generate default constructor
@AllArgsConstructor //generate all argument constructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private  Integer id ;

    @Column(name = "username" ,unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String username ;

    @Column(name = "password")
    @NotNull
    private String password ;

    @Column(name = "email" ,unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String email ;



    @Column(name = "photopath")
    private String photopath ;

    @Column(name = "status")
    @NotNull
    private Boolean status ;

    @Column(name = "addeddatetime")
    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime addeddatetime ;

    @Column(name = "note")
    private String note;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id" ,referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Employee employee_id ;

//   user and role has many to any relationship
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_has_role",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id") ,
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

i need to know the reason for that error and the solution for that
ps:-im a university student and did a sample project and use similar code and it worked fine

when i comment the bolded code app works fine but when i run with that part it give the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dao': Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao' defined in com.suwasethaclinic.dao.EmployeeDao defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.suwasethaclinic.dao.EmployeeDao.getEmployeeListWithoutUserAccount(); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.suwasethaclinic.dao.EmployeeDao.getEmployeeListWithoutUserAccount()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:787) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1418) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:960) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:464) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1358) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1347) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at com.suwasethaclinic.SuwasethaclinicApplication.main(SuwasethaclinicApplication.java:15) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao' defined in com.suwasethaclinic.dao.EmployeeDao defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.suwasethaclinic.dao.EmployeeDao.getEmployeeListWithoutUserAccount(); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.suwasethaclinic.dao.EmployeeDao.getEmployeeListWithoutUserAccount()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1773) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.suwasethaclinic.dao.EmployeeDao.getEmployeeListWithoutUserAccount(); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.suwasethaclinic.dao.EmployeeDao.getEmployeeListWithoutUserAccount()
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:357) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:135) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1820) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.suwasethaclinic.dao.EmployeeDao.getEmployeeListWithoutUserAccount()
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:100) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:70) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:60) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:170) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:252) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:111) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.lang.Integer' with right expression of type 'com.suwasethaclinic.entity.Employee'
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:827) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:732) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:133) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:364) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy123.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:94) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.lang.Integer' with right expression of type 'com.suwasethaclinic.entity.Employee'
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.TypecheckUtil.assertComparable(TypecheckUtil.java:358) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.predicate.SqmInSubQueryPredicate.<init>(SqmInSubQueryPredicate.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitInPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2642) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitInPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$InPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6138) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2244) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$WhereClauseContext.accept(HqlParser.java:5905) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuery(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1159) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:941) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$QuerySpecExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1869) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:926) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$SimpleQueryGroupContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1740) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSelectStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:402) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.buildSemanticModel(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:311) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.interpretHql(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:769) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:819) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Name your field `employee` not `employee_id` next to that use an `exists` and not an `in` query or do the reverse select all employee_ids from the user table and filter out the rest.

Comment: there is one to many realtionship between user and employee and employees primary key is on user table as foreign key

Comment: There is a relation so you can navigate both. An `IN` query is slow or might not even work with large datasets, IN is limited to 1000 values (generally by DBs). So better use EXISTS or in your case NOT EXISTS (or as stated inverse the query for IDs). But the error you have is clearly stated in the exception you are comparing an `INTEGER` (the ID) with an object (the EMPLOYEE) as that is what `employee_id` is in your User. Rename that field and use `u.employee.id` instead in your query.

Comment: you will need to define `@OneToMany` relationship in the employee entity and then you can query it like this `@Query("select p from employee p where p.users.size > 0")`